# How to change the language of my application based on the language of the keyboard?

Tags: android, localization

I am developing an android application. In that application get the language of the keyboard of user android device. If the user keyboard is in French language then The whole application font should be turn into French language.

In that I had tried following demo Example.

### In Values->strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Localizationdemo</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

### in Values-fr->strings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

But in that I only get English language "Hello world" and my keyboard is in French language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope that u have written these lines in your code

```
Locale locale = new Locale("FR");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

because when you set local language as **fr** it will get the strings from Values-**fr** same for other language if you set it as **it** it will consider as you are local language italic and e.t.c..

Note: if your device may be not compatible for all the languages, in that case you need to use external **ttf**

Comment: Nup where Should I Write this code? I mean At onCreate Event?

Comment: if u have any button to change the language write it there , else in launcher Activity on-create

Comment: I meant to say What to do if I want to support my device 5 language. Chiness, Russian, Japaniess, Hindi and English

Comment: The first thing that you need to maintain different string xml files for every language , and you application needs to ask to the user to select an language, based on the selection u can change Locale("---"); value dynamically , and the thing, as soon as user select the language you need to refresh the current activity else in the current activity the change will never occur ,   There is also a chance that all device will never support multilingual so better have look at ttf engines

Comment: But in My way I require that application detact language selected in user phone automatically and start in that language. Is it possible?

Comment: Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(); it returns the device selected language , but make sure how will handle if user selects apart from those 5 language the business logic will small tricky

Comment: Ok Thanks for helping me alot. M trying. Your ans is accepted.

Comment: Heyy in my device english lang is selected but Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();  return French language

Comment: ya i understand you take the result of  Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() and make it as parameter to the  Locale locale = new Locale("---"); hope it resolves your issue

Answer (score 1):

What is your device's language? It won't work if you only change keyboard language.
Try setting the device to French.

Comment: My device lang is English. But I want to change my Application language with user change keyboard language

Comment: Oh I see, in that case Sainath Patwary karnate gives the correct answer